# Which version of NPM works for Node.js 0.2.6

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

On the project page of NPM, it reads:

```
You need node v0.6 or higher to run this program.

To install an old and unsupported version of npm that works on node
0.3 and prior, clone the git repo and dig through the old tags and branches
```

For some reason I have to use Node.js 0.2.x, but I have no idea which version of NPM should I install? As I've tried the latest, and it didn't work for Node.js 0.2.x.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the better reason is, why do you need to use such an ancient version of Node? The SO community is going to be able to answer that question much more effectively than trying to get NPM working with an old version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

npm version 0.2.19 is the last one that works with node 0.2.

Don't use it.  It's terrible.  Upgrade node.